# Oracle Number Type Column not converted from Bytes when it comes to Kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm connecting `Oracle` to `Kafka` by using a `JDBC` connector. When data comes in from `Oracle`, it is converted correctly except for the `Oracle` Columns that are Numbers. For such columns, the data is not decoded.  The following is an example:

> {"ID":"\u0004{","TYPE":"\u0000Ù","MODE":"bytes":"\u0007"},"STAT_TEMP":{"string":"TESTING"}}

I should mention that I'm also connecting the `Kafka` to spark such that I get the same output in the `spark`.

I'm wondering what is the best way to convert the data?

Whether to do it in `Kafka` or `spark`. If in Kafka, what is your suggestion in how to convert it?

Comment: What does Spark JDBC give you? What version of Kafka Connect?

Comment: Well this is an issue we faced as well. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/101
It has trouble converting NUMBER data type without precision.

Comment: I'm using Kafka 0.11.0.0.
The spark connects to Kafka and the output in spark is exactly the same as in a Kafka consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your connector config numeric.mapping

```
"numeric.mapping":"best_fit"
```

for more explication [here](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/7bb46a0b6d27982a5fb7a103bb7c95b9)